# Count comma delimited values and replicate a value equal times in R

Tags: r, rep

Given the following example data ...

```
id                               Proteins
522     Q9UHC7-4;Q9UHC7-3;Q9UHC7-2;Q9UHC7
523                                Q9UHV7
524                       Q9Y6T7-2;Q9Y6T7
525                       Q9Y6T7-2;Q9Y6T7
```

... I would like to create a third column with each `id` times the number of semicolon delimited values of each row. More specifically something like that:

```
id                               Proteins     newCol
522     Q9UHC7-4;Q9UHC7-3;Q9UHC7-2;Q9UHC7    522;522;522;522
523                                Q9UHV7    523
524                       Q9Y6T7-2;Q9Y6T7    524;524
525                       Q9Y6T7-2;Q9Y6T7    525;525
```

I have tried this `dt$newCol <- rep(dt$id, lengths(str_split(dt$Proteins, ";")))` but doesn't work since it creates a longer list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
library(stringr)
df$newCol <- str_replace_all(df$Proteins, "[^;]+", as.character(df$id))
```

Output

```
> df
   id                          Proteins          newCol
1 522 Q9UHC7-4;Q9UHC7-3;Q9UHC7-2;Q9UHC7 522;522;522;522
2 523                            Q9UHV7             523
3 524                   Q9Y6T7-2;Q9Y6T7         524;524
4 525                   Q9Y6T7-2;Q9Y6T7         525;525
```

---

Another Base R solution suggested by **@markus**

```
df1$new <- Map(gsub, pattern = "[^;]+", replacement = df1$id, x = df1$Proteins)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(newCol = map2_chr(id, str_count(Proteins, ";") + 1, ~str_c(rep(.x, .y), collapse = ";")))
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R solution would be to count number of times `";"` occurs, add +1 to it, repeat the `id`s accordingly. Paste the id's together using `tapply` to create `newCol`.

```
x <- rep(df$id, lengths(regmatches(df$Proteins, gregexpr(";", df$Proteins))) + 1)
df$newCol <- tapply(x, x, paste0, collapse = ';')
df

#   id                          Proteins          newCol
#1 522 Q9UHC7-4;Q9UHC7-3;Q9UHC7-2;Q9UHC7 522;522;522;522
#2 523                            Q9UHV7             523
#3 524                   Q9Y6T7-2;Q9Y6T7         524;524
#4 525                   Q9Y6T7-2;Q9Y6T7         525;525
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use a `for` loop with `gsub`

```
for(i in seq_len(nrow(df1))) df1$newCol[i] <- gsub("([[:alnum:]-]+)", df1$id[i], df1$Proteins[i])
df1
#  id                          Proteins          newCol
#1 522 Q9UHC7-4;Q9UHC7-3;Q9UHC7-2;Q9UHC7 522;522;522;522
#2 523                            Q9UHV7             523
#3 524                   Q9Y6T7-2;Q9Y6T7         524;524
#4 525                   Q9Y6T7-2;Q9Y6T7         525;525
```